# Get image extension from dynamic image url

Tags: php

I am stuck on this, hoping somebody has an idea.

I am trying to determine the file extension of a remote **dynamic** image path.

`https://d2sh4fq2xsdeg9.cloudfront.net/contentAsset/image/93e9fb86-8f30-4fea-bdb9-90d63eb67e44/image/byInode/1/filter/Resize,Jpeg/jpeg_q/70/resize_w/1000`

or, say, `https://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000`

I have tried using `parse_url` and `finfo_file` as well as `SplFileInfo` but none of those worked in my testing of them. Maybe something in one of them I do not know about(?).

I thought about using `file_get_contents` -> `file_put_contents` and saving it locally, but that would not work without knowing the file extension, which is the root cause of all of this to begin with.

I cannot convert it into an image `data:` *(base64)* because that requires knowing the mime type, and that is not possible, as far as I know, without, again, knowing the file extension and/or saving it locally.

And, one cannot just assume that it is always going to be a xyz-file type.

And, doing some type of preg_match just seems like the worse way to go about this, as different developers/programs uses different methods for this kind of dynamic image resizing techniques.

I suppose I could always do a `strpos($haystack, $needle)` checking for a combination of needles *(gif,png,jpeg,etc)* but, well, uggggghhh to that idea, eh.

So, just thought that I would post here and see if anybody has any good idea on how to go about getting the extension from dynamic image uri's.

Comment: try [exif_imagetype](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) that function does the actual image header parsing to determine the type.

Comment: @bansi - woot. I knew there had to be something out there... seems to be working, thanks mate!!

Comment: also you can use [ImageMagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) if you want more details.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can make a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request and check the `content_type` of the response header.

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://d2sh4fq2xsdeg9.cloudfront.net/contentAsset/image/93e9fb86-8f30-4fea-bdb9-90d63eb67e44/image/byInode/1/filter/Resize,Jpeg/jpeg_q/70/resize_w/1000");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_getinfo($ch)['content_type'];
curl_close($ch);
```

**Output:**

```
image/jpeg
```

**#Update:**

If all you want to do is to just check the image extension and not want image file in return, then you can just make a [HEAD request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) as mentioned by **@SalmanA** in the comments.

You need to add the following line to above curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"HEAD");
```

Comment: this one works as far as the server sends you correct mime type.

Comment: giving you +1 for awesome idea. :)

Comment: @bansi I am assuming that is the case. If the server data is not trustable, never make a request in the first place.

Comment: there can be some misleading info, when the resource is not a file, and the developer tries to send it and sends wrong mime type, like `image/jpeg` instead if `image/png` and this works in browser, as far as the type is some image. Also I have seen image streamed as binary, and javascript rendering it as image, to confuse the browser and prevent users from a simple `save as`. But your solution is nice and simple +1

Comment: @bansi Fair enough. Can you give me some site example where image is streamed as binary. It will be a good learning experience for me.

Comment: You can simply make a `HEAD` request instead of fetching the whole file (a sane server might return the content type). If you're fetching the whole file then you might as well double check using fileinfo functions.

Answer (score 2):

First take the mime-type of the image using finfo.

```
$url = "https://d2sh4fq2xsdeg9.cloudfront.net/contentAsset/image/93e9fb86-8f30-4fea-bdb9-90d63eb67e44/image/byInode/1/filter/Resize,Jpeg/jpeg_q/70/resize_w/1000";
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type = $finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($url));
print_r($type);
```

then get file extension using below

```
function getExtension ($mime_type){

    $extensions = array('image/jpeg' => 'jpeg',
                        'text/xml' => 'xml');

    // Add as many other Mime Types / File Extensions as you like

    return $extensions[$mime_type];

}
```

Comment: Hey Jay. Thanks for sharing. I did try `finfo`, but I only tried the `finfo_file` and that would obviously not work. Did not give the `buffer()` method a try, or even know about it to be honest. Neat technique, and again, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @aleba this requires php_fileinfo extension enabled. You did not mention in your OP what error you were getting (_none of those worked in my testing of them_ is not does not help)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$url = 'https://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000';
$type = get_headers($url, 1)["Content-Type"];
echo $type;
```